# PHP MySQL Information Update Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

[Image for Database Columns from Workbench here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NsXe.jpg)

Thanks beforehand to everyone who takes the trouble to review and answer my question here.
I am working on a website where I am required to make a dashboard for my registered visitors so that they can view and edit their profile information. However, I have run into some problem with my code. 
When a user submits changes to his profile, the server updates the information stored in a MySQL table and informs the user that the information has been updated.
On the outside, it seems to be smoothly working. When I upload a profile picture or set a new name or set a new email address, it shows me "Successfully Updated". But when I check the 'actual' database entries (using Workbench) I find that absolutely nothing has been updated.

P.S. I have already checked my source code for errors on http://phpcodechecker.com . And my MySQL connection is correctly working(because I have used the same snippet in other php files as well).

P.P.S (if at all necessary) I am using Windows 10 64-bit and PHP 7 with IIS 10 Server and MySQL Workbench for Windows version 6.2.4(64 bit)

The Source Codes:
**edit_profile.php**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    require('./functions.php');

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
        $profile_picture = $_POST["profile_picture"];

        echo 'Changing Contents of your profile..';
        if ($name != $_SESSION["name"]) {
            if (setUserName($user_id, $name)) {
                echo 'Successfully changed User Name.<br/>';
            } else {
                echo 'Unsuccessful';
            }
        }
        if ($email != $_SESSION["email"] && $email != "") {
            if (setEmail($user_id, $email)) {
                echo 'Successfully changed Email.<br/>';
            } else {
                echo 'Unsuccessful';
            }
        }
        if ($profile_picture != getProfilePicture_base64_encoded($user_id) && $profile_picture != "") {
            if (setProfilePicture_base64_encoded($user_id, $profile_picture)) {
                echo 'Successfully changed Profile Picture.<br/>';
            } else {
                echo 'Unsuccessful';
            }
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>StoryDorado | Edit Profile</title>
                <meta name="theme-color" content="">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta name="robots" content="nocache,noarchive,nofollow,nosnippet">
                <meta name="Description" content="">
                <meta name="keywords" content="">
            </head>
            <body>
                <form action="edit_profile.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    Set New Profile Picture (Max. 15 MB): <input name="profile_picture" id="profile_picture" accept="image/JPEG" type="file"><br/>
                    Set User Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br/>
                    Set New E-mail:<input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
                </form>
                <br/>
                <div id="Current_Info" style="display:block;">
                    <pre>
                            Your Current Information:
                            1.Profile Picture:
                        <?php
                        $profile_picture = getProfilePicture_base64_encoded($_SESSION["user_id"]);
                        if ($profile_picture === NULL) {
                            echo '<img src="default.jpg" />';
                        } else {
                            echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $profile_picture . '" />';
                        }
                        ?><br/>
                            2. User Name:
                        <?php echo $_SESSION["name"]; ?><br/>
                            3. E-Mail:
                        <?php
                        if ($_SESSION["email"] != "") {
                            echo $_SESSION["email"];
                        } else {
                            echo 'Not         Provided';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </pre>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

**And functions.php located in the same folder**

```
<?php

    function encrypt_password($password) {
        $cost = 10;
        $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
        $salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
        $hash = crypt($password, $salt);
        return $hash;
    }

    function check_user($user_id, $password) {
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login_system") or die("Connection Failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $list = $conn->query($query);
        $result = false;
        while ($row = $list->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($user_id == $row["user_id"] && $row["subscription_code"] != 0 && hash_equals($row["subscription_code"], crypt($password, $row["subscription_code"]))) {
                $result = true;
            }
        }
        $conn->close();
        return $result;
    }

    function getProfilePicture_base64_encoded($user_id) {
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login_system") or die("Connection Failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'";
        $list = $conn->query($query);
        $image = null;
        while ($row = $list->fetch_assoc()) {
            $image = $row["profile_picture"];
        }
        $conn->close();
        return $image;
    }

    function setProfilePicture_base64_encoded($user_id, $picture) {
        $picture = base64_encode($picture);
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login_system") or die("Connection Failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
        $query = "UPDATE users SET profile_picture='" . $picture . "' WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "';";
        $result = false;
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            $result = true;
        }
        $conn->close();
        return $result;
    }

    function setUserName($user_id, $name) {
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login_system") or die("Connection Failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
        $query = "UPDATE users SET name='" . $name . "' WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "';";
        $result = false;
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            $result = true;
        }
        $conn->close();
        return $result;
    }

    function setPassword($user_id, $password) { //WARNING: Be Cautious About When You Let A User Change His Password
        $password = encrypt_password($password);
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login_system") or die("Connection Failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
        $query = "UPDATE users SET subscription_code='" . $password . "' WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "';";
        $result = false;
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            $result = true;
        }
        $conn->close();
        return $result;
    }

    function setEmail($user_id, $email) {
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login_system") or die("Connection Failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
        $query = "UPDATE users SET email='" . $email . "' WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "';";
        $result = false;
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            $result = true;
        }
        $conn->close();
        return $result;
    }

    function UnRegister($user_id) { //WARNING: Be Cautious About This. Changes are not reversible. Provide proper sure-checking to end users.
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login_system") or die("Connection Failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
        $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "';";
        $result = false;
        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            $result = true;
        }
        $conn->close();
        return $result;
    }

    function validate($data) {
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

What could be the cause of this? And how to fix it?

**EDIT :**

I ran the same query I have used in the functions above in MySQL Workbench. There was an error! It said :
Executing:

```
UPDATE `login_system`.`users` SET `name`='Rojaxius' WHERE `user_id`='facebook000000000';

ERROR 1175: 1175: You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `login_system`.`users` SET `name`='Mr Who' WHERE `user_id`='facebook000000000'
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
```

Now what does that mean ?

Comment: remember to clean your inputs before posting them.

Comment: isnt any of the update working?

Comment: try using a proper IDE, Eclipse or netbeans. your code isn't properly indented

Comment: Sorry.. My bad. New to StackOverflow.

Comment: you dont necessarily have to instantiate your DB connection everytime. establish it on one file, say db_con.php, then include it on this page, then you can access it as a global variable.

Comment: what is datatype of user_id? if it is int then remove single quotes around user_id from queries. Then try to update

Comment: Yes i had overlooked that in this class, partly because I copied and pasted much of the code over and over again from another class file. But that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: user_id is varchar(255).

Comment: In each of the functions in functions.php, you are testing if the connection fails or not. But you use that result as a result of the query you ran. That's incorrect! Eg. if the WHERE clause in your SQL statement fails, then the function will still act as if the update succeeded... but in your table nothing will change.

Comment: So how to ensure that the query was successful?

Comment: Probably using affected_rows() function ?

Comment: For updates/inserts (altering tables) you can use the object property affected_rows    If it's 0 then nothing was changed. If > 0 then you can assume it was True and let the user know it was changed succesfully...

Comment: Try ```mysqli_affected_rows()``` to check is there any rows affecting or not - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: your answer crossed mine. Yes. Try that :-)

Comment: side notes: you sould check post values before injecting them directly in query strings, something like php's `filter_input`. To have a more secure system, you should also add a way to check if the user exists and has actual permission to modify. I also read somewhere that `mcrypt` is not so secure anymore (if someone can confirm: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the insight @Werner . Now, the query returns unsuccessful. But why?

Comment: I read something similar @Kaddath. I've temporarily used that encryption function, I'll change it before i proceed to production environment.

Comment: Hey @Roy 
`$conn->query($query);
if( $conn->affected_rows > 0 ) { 
   return true;
}  else { 
  return false;
} `

Doesn't work?

Please check [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: @Werner Yes it works. But it returns -1. That means, the query failed. But why? It's not a problem with account privileges on localhost because all other queries in other php files seem to work just fine. Only this one had me bugging for the last 12 hours.

Comment: Then it ran into an error ;-) 
You can also access the error it ran into. That's another mysqli class property. In your case $conn->errno and $conn->error_list and $conn->error   Pls read: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thanks. I'll get back to you with the error.

Comment: I used   `if($conn->mysqli_affected_rows>-1){
  $result=true;
  }else{
   print_r($conn->error_list);
  }` and it returned _Changing Contents of your profile..Array ( ) Unsuccessful_

Comment: So what does this mean?

Comment: What function you used? So I can find it in the code.

Comment: I used the function setUserName in the above result.

Comment: name is a reserved keyword in MySQL... Maybe thats conflicting. What happens if you change the column name in the table and sources eg into fullname or so. Or using backticks:    `    to enclose field names in your source might help also.

Comment: actually i advise using backticks. Sorry cant give a fast example as the character is a markup character in this editor... Just enclose the column names  `name` and `user_id` with the backtick character in the update query and then see what happens...

Comment: if you still need help please post what the function setUserName looks like right now in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: NAME is a keyword in MySQL but it is not a reserved keyword. Please see [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Yeah, I read that thanks. 
Change this in your code:
$conn->mysqli_affected_rows should be $conn->affected_rows
 and change the -1 back in 0 as zero means no row was update thus something was wrong (rec not found)

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Will get back to you if it doesnt work.

Comment: Correct. But you're not using that function. It is an object property from the object you created by doing `$conn=new mysqli()`.

Comment: Did all the changes, still prints "Changing Contents of your profile..Array ( ) Unsuccessful"

Comment: Ok and the user_id you use to change the name for is existing in the table?

Comment: Yes it does. I think I have found what the problem could be..

Comment: Enlighten me please

Comment: I've edited my post. Please see.

Comment: You are using safe update mode on the server. It's like "paranoia mode". : -) 
Whenever the MySQL server sees operations on the database that may look like "hacks" (SQL Injections), it will stall and give an error.  
In your case it says: "You tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column". 
Yes that update statement is also typical for a hack statement... Juste create an Primary index on the table with the user_id as primary key/column. That will solve it. 
Or tell your server to get out of safe mode, latter is not recommended for internet-service ofcourse.

Comment: Thanks @Werner . I got it to work. I'll give a brief detail of what happened : I generally use my administrator account to do coding. However, I've set it to Performance Mode on Windows Settings which really makes the page's texts look bad. So, I created a Guest Account and used that for viewing this. But as you can see, I had'nt hoped for this. Bad luck I guess.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Can you please post an example? @zaph

Comment: Just use the PHP functions `password_hash` and `password_verify` instead of encryption, SO is full of examples. Using methods that are known not to be secure puts users at risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Everyone for spending time on my question. I could not have found the answer without having consulted you. But your insights revealed a lot and I finally found out why the statements were not working. It was simply because the `user_id` column in my database was not set as UNIQUE. So, on Safe Mode, the WHERE clause made no sense to the program since it could'nt know for sure if there were 2 same `user_id` entries. Hence the problems. Now it has been fixed. I decided to share this answer in case someone else gets caught up in this mess and wastes 12 hours on it :)
Thanks to all of you.

```
<Happy Coding/>
```

Comment: Thumbs up! Happy Coding! :-) 

Almost forgot - change the pass in the db connection string. You've pasted it up in one of the 209237 comments above.

Comment: Phew! Good catch! Almost missed it.